# In light-box POP-UP, Server side function not calling

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In POP-UP section, i am having one query form in that on-click(server) event is not triggering if i click on the Save button. 
Please guide me how to call the on server side event. Below are the code

Light Box Code;

```
$(".no-video-btn2").click(function() {
    $(".no-video-popup2").lightbox_me({ centered: true, onLoad: function() { } });
});
```

asp Button Code:

```
<asp:Button id="btnJobTypePopupSave" runat="server" class="select-button" Text="Save" onclick="btnJobTypePopupSave_Click" />
```

Asp Sever Side Code:

```
protected void btnJobTypePopupSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Got the Solution for this, instead of asp button use Link-Button it will work, because if we use asp:Button browser treat as input type, in pop-up input type is not supporting. If you use Asp:LinkButton browser treat as an anchor.